# Laravel - orderBy not working on relationship collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I recently moved a Laravel website to a different server with the same setup (slightly different versions of php, mariadb, etc.) and have run into an interesting problem.

I'm using the package [Team-Tea-Time/laravel-forum](https://github.com/Team-Tea-Time/laravel-forum) (formerly riari/laravel-forum) to provide message board functionalities. In the forum every thread has a link to get to the newest post, which worked fine before the move. After the move those links lead to the oldest/first post instead.

The functionality is part of the [Thread model](https://github.com/Team-Tea-Time/laravel-forum/blob/4.0/src/Models/Thread.php), specifically the function getLastPostAttribute().

When trying to get to the bottom of this, I realized that the orderBy on the posts relationship is simply not having any effect. No matter what attribute I sort by (e.g. created_at, sequence) and which sort direction I request, it's always the same post order and the same first post being returned.

Example of a thread with 1811 posts with different timestamps and sequence numbers:

Ordering by sequence ASC works correctly, the first post being the one with the smalles sequence number. This is however also the default order of that relationship (see Model).

```
$t->posts()->orderBy('sequence', 'asc')->first();
Riari\Forum\Models\Post {#3268
    id: 113544,
    thread_id: 3995,
    author_id: 191,
    sequence: 1,
    created_at: "2018-05-08 08:21:20",
    updated_at: "2018-05-08 10:51:41",
    deleted_at: null,
    vote_count: 0,
}
```

Now when I change the sort order to desc, it should return the post with the highest sequence number. But instead I get the same result as above.

```
$t->posts()->orderBy('sequence', 'desc')->first();
Riari\Forum\Models\Post {#3297
    id: 113544,
    thread_id: 3995,
    author_id: 191,
    sequence: 1,
    created_at: "2018-05-08 08:21:20",
    updated_at: "2018-05-08 10:51:41",
    deleted_at: null,
    vote_count: 0,
}
```

This is the post that should be returned when sorting by sequence desc:

```
Riari\Forum\Models\Post {#3332
    id: 196449,
    thread_id: 3995,
    author_id: 534,
    sequence: 1814,
    created_at: "2020-12-16 14:55:54",
    updated_at: "2020-12-16 14:55:54",
    deleted_at: null,
    vote_count: 0,
}
```

Has anybody experienced this before? Everything else works fine after the move, I'm clueless as to what would cause such a specific error.

Comment: both have `sequence` equal to 1 so there is no order. Refering to the `id` it seems to be the same entry

Comment: That's exactly the issue - that's the same post being returned both times, which is why the sequence is the same. But there are 1810 other entries with different squence numers. So the call with sorting by sequence DESC should have returned the one with a sequence of 1811.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the post that should be the correct result?

Comment: Is sequence a column in the `posts` table or an accessor? Can you post the `Thread` model? (particularly the `posts()` relationship definition), the `Post` model and the `posts` table migration?

Comment: Also, can you confirm the query being run with `$t->posts()->orderBy('sequence', 'desc')->toSql()` ? Do you get the desired result if you run the query directly in the database?

Comment: I added more info to the post. I had added a link to the Thread model if anybody wants to look at the post.

`$t->posts()->orderBy('sequence', 'desc')->toSql()`

returns

`"select * from forum_posts where forum_posts.thread_id = ? and forum_posts.thread_id is not null and forum_posts.deleted_at is null order by created_at asc, sequence desc"`

It looks like by orderBy is only being used as a secondary order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at the relation definition in the source code of [Thread.php](https://github.com/Team-Tea-Time/laravel-forum/blob/4.0/src/Models/Thread.php), you see that `posts` are already ordered by `created_at` by default:

```
public function posts()
{
        $withTrashed = config('forum.preferences.display_trashed_posts') || Gate::allows('viewTrashedPosts');
        $query = $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at');
        return $withTrashed ? $query->withTrashed() : $query;
}
```

I think you would need to override the `posts` method, remove the `orderBy('created_at')` statement, and then your own orderBy will work.

Comment: Yes, this looks promising, just saw that thanks to the ->toSql() function mentioned above. Strangely the same code worked fine on the old server. I will give it a quick try now.

Comment: Yep, overwriting this function fixed the issue for me. Still strange that this package worked fine before .. I'll let the package owner know in case anybody elsse runs into this. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Looking at the [history](https://github.com/Team-Tea-Time/laravel-forum/commit/c31ca524089878801366df581a3a89105c19c43e#diff-e851bc30a03deef7dec8662e299e8e8ded4ff23207b21609dc03f2a76734f3ab), the default ordering seems to be added in February.